# How to manage a third-party DLL event within his wrapper DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, dll

I'm a beginner!
I made a wrapper DLL (DLL_A) of a third-party DLL (DLL_B). 
Below you can find a simplyfied example:

The DLL_B class Class_B expose (i can view only the signature from metadata):

```
public delegate void eveHandler(bool ret_B);

public class cls_B
{
    public cls_B(string init);

    public event eveHandler eve;

    public void req(eveHandler reqHandler = null);

}
```

Inside DLL_A:

```
public class cls_A
{     
    private cls_B objClsB;
    private bool continueWorking = true;

    public cls_A()
    {
        objClsB = new cls_B("test");
        objClsB.ev += new eveHandler(this.eveManager);
    }

    public eveManager(bool ret_A)
    {
        continueWorking = false;
    }

    public request()
    {
        objClsB.req();

        int i = 0;
        While (continueWorking && i < 100)
        {
            //Do a lot of stuff...
            i++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Then inside the main app:

```
cls_A objClsA = new cls_A();
objClsA.request();
MessageBox.Show("Done!", "MyApp");
```

It works, but it seems that the `eveManager()` is only called when it exit from the `objClsA.request();` , before execute `MessageBox.Show("Done!", "MyApp");`.
In fact if I remove the `&& i < 100` part it will stuck inside the while loop, but I need that the event stop the loop.

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The behaviour you describe reflects the code you have posted.  It is not clear what you want to happen instead.

Comment: Hi! I need that when an event from Cls_B occur, it exit from the while. Thank you

Comment: What happens if you remove the `&& i < 100` ?

Comment: It will stuck inside the while loop... and this is the issue. I can't understand where I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: you do realize that noting is calling the event eve ( so continueWorking is always true )?

Comment: The event is rised by the DLL_B in reply to an "objClsB.req()" call. But it seems that this can't happen when it is in the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution founded! It works if I start the `objClsB.req()` on another thread this way:

```
public request()
{
    Thread thr = new Thread(delegate() { objClsB.req(); });
    thr.Start();        

    int i = 0;
    While (continueWorking)
    {
        //Do a lot of stuff...
    } 
}
```